# Loomis and Sternberg, "relational inverse"

Tags: proof-explanation, relations

A theorem on page 15 of Loomis and Sternberg's book, *Advanced Calculus*, is:

> A mapping $f: A \to B$ has an inverse if and only if it is bijective, in which case its inverse is its relational inverse $f^{-1}$.

I am not completely clear what they mean by "relational inverse." My understanding is this. A function $f$ can be regarded as its graph (which is itself a relation), so it's exactly a subset of $S \subset A \times B$ where for every $a \in A$, there exists a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in S$. The "inverse" of this is then the set of ordered pairs $(b,a)$ such that $(a,b) \in S$.

Is this the correct idea?

Comment: It is correct. The relational inverse happens to be a function in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. We define the relational inverse (sometimes called transpose or converse) $R^{-1}$ to $R \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \times A)$ to be

$$R^{-1} = \{ (b,a) \mid (a,b) \in R \}$$

In the case of $R$ a bijective relation (or function, which is formally a relation), then $R^{-1}$ itself also meets the condition for being a function - which is what we desire for an "inverse" function (one where the composition of functions - or of relations - "undoes" the other in some sense).

(A relation $R$ on $A$ is bijective if for each $a \in A$, we may find $b \in A$ where $(a,b) \in R$ - the function property - and for any $b \in A$ there is one and only one $a \in A$ where $(a,b) \in R$ - the bijective property. If you flip around the coordinates, notice that $R$ is bijective iff $R^{-1}$ is too.)